# Bootstrap 4 - the content in the navigation bar moves slightly to the right when the page is shorter than the screen height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 - the content in the  navigation bar moves slightly to the right when the page is shorter than the screen height - this doesn't happen with longer pages. I have posted the code from two pages. A home page which is the longer page and a login page which is shorter and twitches.

I am wondering if the solution is to give a minimum height for the content - though I would prefer not to override Boostrap

Longer content with static non twitching navbar

```
<!-- head start -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Home page of MVC test </title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<!-- head end -->
<body>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MVC Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation_bar" aria-controls="navigation_bar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation_bar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li  class='nav-item active'><a href='http://mvc.test/home' class='nav-link'  >Home</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/posts' class='nav-link'  >Posts</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/about' class='nav-link'  >About</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/register' class='nav-link'  >Register</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/login' class='nav-link'  >Login</a></li>        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<!-- page content start -->
<div class="container">
    <!-- start of row -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- page content left start -->
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                Home            </h1>
            <h2 ><a href = "#" >A first post - I do say</a ></h2 >
<p class="lead">
    by <a href="index.php">Start Bootstrap</a>
</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>2020-02-03 11:00:00</p>
<hr>
<img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt="">
<hr>
<p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    <hr>
<h2 ><a href = "#" >A second post</a ></h2 >
<p class="lead">
    by <a href="index.php">Start Bootstrap</a>
</p>
<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>2020-02-03 16:00:00</p>
<hr>
<img class="img-fluid" src="http://placehold.it/900x300" alt="">
<hr>
<p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Read More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    <hr>
        </div>
        <!-- page content left end -->
        <!-- page content right start -->
        <div class="col-md-4 bg-light ">
                <!-- Blog Search Well -->
    <div class="pt-3 ml-1">
        <h4>Blog Search</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                        </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /.input-group -->
    </div>

    <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
    <div class="pt-1 ml-1">
        <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Category Name</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Side Widget Well -->
    <div class="bg-light">
        <h4>Side Widget Well</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore, perspiciatis adipisci accusamus laudantium odit aliquam repellat tempore quos aspernatur vero.</p>
    </div>
        </div>
        <!-- page content right end -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of row -->
    <!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014 </p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</footer>

</div>
<!-- end of container -->

<!-- jQuery -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
<!-- page content end -->
```

Shorter content with content that moves or twitches to the right

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>This is a login title </title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MVC Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation_bar" aria-controls="navigation_bar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation_bar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/home' class='nav-link'  >Home</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/posts' class='nav-link'  >Posts</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/about' class='nav-link'  >About</a></li><li class='nav-item'><a href='http://mvc.test/register' class='nav-link'  >Register</a></li><li  class='nav-item active'><a href='http://mvc.test/login' class='nav-link'  >Login</a></li>        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
   </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">

                <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                    <div class="card card-light bg-light mt-5">
                                                <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                        <p>Please fill in your credentials</p>
                        <form action="http://mvc.test/login" method="post" >
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email: <sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg " value="">
                                <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password">Password: <sup>*</sup></label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg " value="">
                                <span class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <a href="http://mvc.test/register" class="btn btn-default btn-block" role="button">Don't have an account? Login</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"  >

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- /.row -->
    <hr>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014 </p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</footer>

</div>
<!-- end of container -->

<!-- jQuery -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

thanks C

Comment: Is it the browser scroll bar disappearing that makes things jump to right?

Comment: Yes thanks - I googled around quite a bit and then noticed that it was indeed the appearance and disappearance of my vertical scroll bar that was causing the issue of my nav bar contents  jumping to the right. I thankfully found a solution and I will put it in the answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This is a solution to my 'twitching' nav bar, see above. I've read that this is not a good CSS and that it doesn't work in opera - however I've seen that the BBC website uses this if that means anything.